# Directory.GetFilesNameWithoutExtension() Array

Tags: c#, arrays, file, directory

I have several files in a folder.  I want the names of the files (without their extensions) in an `Array`.  Is it possible to retrieve the entire list of files like this?  The closest I have come is `Directory.GetFiles("FolderName")` which returns an array of `"FolderName\FileName.Extensions"`.  Is it possible to have an array of just `"FileName"` for each file?  The problem with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` is that it only returns it for a single file.

(Note:  I am looking for a more elegant way than `String.Split()` or `String.SubString()`)

This is what Directory.GetFiles() provides:

```
{"FolderName\File1.ext", "FolderName\File2.ext"}
```

This is what I want (elegantly):

```
{"File1", "File2"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're looking for the [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) method:

```
var filenames = Directory.EnumerateFiles("FolderName")
                         .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
                         .ToArray();
```

**Edit**: If you want to learn about the `Select` operator, you should study LINQ, which is a great tool for boosting productivity in .NET. The above could be equivalently expressed as:

```
var filenames = Directory.GetFiles("FolderName");
for (int i = 0; i < filenames.Length; ++i)
    filenames[i] = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filenames[i]);
```

Comment: That line of code is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you!  (I was aware of Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(), but not aware of the EnumerateFiles() method or Select() method you showed here.  Still a C# newb, but I am learning thanks to you wonderful people!!)